# Will moving to a CAS array object in Exchange 2010 mess up currently configured clients pre-CAS array config?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, load-balancing, cas

I'm planning for an Exchange 2010 environment that is looking to move from operating on a singular CAS server to having multiple CAS servers with a CAS array object configured.  There are clients with Outlook profiles that are referencing the current CAS server and not the CAS array object.

Will creating the CAS array object and then configuring the Mailboxes RPC CAS to point to the Array object be enough to update user Outlook profiles and cause minimal disruption to the organization or am I missing anything else that would need to be configured?

I've already configured a hardware load balancer and confirmed services are reachable through the virtual IP so I just need to cut over from the single CAS to the HWLB CAS array object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice in Exchange 2010 was to always create a CAS Array - even if you were only using one server. Not that this helps you much right now.

Note: I have not had to do this, so I'm speaking in theory as opposed to practical, first-hand knowledge.

You will likely need to update the RpcClientAccessServer attribute on the databases to the new FQDN of the CAS Array. Using EMS:

```
Set-MailboxDatabase <name of DB> -RpcClientAccessServer “casarray.mydomain.com”
```

Outlook 2010 clients may need to be restarted to pick up the change and redo autodiscover. Outlook 2003 clients will probably need to manually have their profiles updated to point to the CASArray.

Or, look at migrating to Exchange 2013 which does away with the CAS Array anyway.. :)

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah this was something I 'inherited' as a task and all the write-ups speak about configuring CAS in the context of, "before this is production, do this."

Comment: Marking as the answer since no more activity.  Thanks for the input!